# System.Exception: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154) Error for Silverlight 4 webcam

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have copied the silverlight videochat samplecode from [silverlightvideochat](http://silverlightvideochat.codeplex.com) to try a simple videochat application but getting the below mentioned error while capturing image.

> System.Exception: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154)
>       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
>       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CaptureGraph_Start(CaptureSource Source)
>       at System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource.Start()
>       at SocketCoder_WebCamSender.MainPage.btnActivate_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

I am using 64 bit Operating System, silverlight-4

I am getting the above error on `_capture.Start()` method for capturing image in 
silverlight 4.

```csharp
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Start The Camera
   if (_capture != null)
   {
      _capture.Stop();
      _capture.VideoCaptureDevice = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice();
      VideoBrush videoBrush = new VideoBrush();
      videoBrush.SetSource(_capture);
      rectVideo.Fill = videoBrush;
      if (CaptureDeviceConfiguration.AllowedDeviceAccess || CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess())
      {
        _capture.Start();
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried running the application by changing Target Platform to x86 but no success.

Please suggest

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the declaration of `_capture` to your post.  But this sounds like it cannot find the web cam driver, or its looking for the wrong one.

Comment: @paqogomez: webcam is working properly in skype videochat on same machine, and declaration of _capture is  'private CaptureSource _capture = new CaptureSource();'

Comment: Is there any code where you set the driver name that is to be used? `Class not registered` sounds like a dll that is not registered on the machine.  Perhaps a driver.

Comment: I am using FJ.Core.dll